# Leer segunda hoja de googlesheet usando googlesheet4

Tags: r, rstudio, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un excel en googledrive que tiene dos hojas:

1. Hoja A
2. Hoja B

Para descargar de googlesheet en R estoy usando `googlesheet4`, de la siguiente forma:

```
library(googlesheets4)
library(tidyverse)

# Autentifico la cuenta
drive_auth()

# Obtengo los metadatos del excel
target <- gs4_get("URL_FICHERO")

# Obtengo la ID del excel
ssid <- as_sheets_id(target)

# Leo el fichero
read_sheet(ssid)
```

El problema que tengo es que por defecto sólo descarga la "Hoja A", y necesito la segunda, ¿existe alguna manera de poder indicar la hoja exacta a descargar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes revisar la documentación de la función https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/reference/read_sheet.html.

Ahí se indica que puedes usar el argumento `sheet` dentro de al función para especificar qué hoja leer.

```r
read_sheet(ssid, sheet = 2)
```

Comment: Cierto, toda la razón, ya he podido acceder a la segunda hoja. ¡Gracias!